# Derived class error: undefined type

Tags: c++

Code looks like this:

```
class B {/*something*/};

class D1: public B {
public:
void set() = 0;
friend int D2::get(D1&);
private: 
int a;
}
class D2: public B {
public:
int get(D1& d) {return d.a;}
}
```

I've included `"B.h"` in both derived class' .h files(`"D1.h" and "D2.h"`) and also "`D2.h`" in D1, `"D1.h"` in D2...but keep getting compiling error:

```
...\D2.h ... use of undefined type D1
```

So what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created a circular inclusion: you included `D1.h` into `D2.h` and you also included `D2.h` into `D1.h`. Circular inclusion never works and never achieves anything.

Your circular inclusion is a direct consequence of circular dependency between your class definitions. In your code both class definitions refer to each other in a way that requires both class types to be complete (to be completely defined). This means that your code, as is, cannot be compiled, regardless of what you do. You need to break the circular dependency between class definitions.

In your case it can be done in the following way.

Keep `D1.h` unchanged, i.e. keep including `D2.h` into `D1.h` and keep the definition of class `D1` as is.

However, *do not* include `D1.h` into `D2.h` Instead introduce a forward declaration of `D1` into `D2.h`

```
class D1;
```

Change the definition of `D2` to

```
class D2: public B {
public:
  int get(D1& d);
};
```

Note: do not attempt to define method `get` right in the definition of class `D2`. You have to *relocate* the definition of `D2::get` to some other place, where the full definition of `D1` is also visible (like in `D2.cpp` for example, which should include both `D1.h` and `D2.h`)

```
int D2::get(D1& d) 
{
  return d.a;
}
```

That's it. A side-effect of defining `D2::get` this way is that it becomes non-inline. If you really want to keep it inline, you'll have to define it as

```
inline int D2::get(D1& d) 
{
  return d.a;
}
```

and also make sure it is somehow included only *after* the full definition of `D1`. You can place it, for example, into a third header file (`D2_aux.h` or something like that) and remember to include it *after* the `D1.h`.

Of course, a better way to try to solve this issue is to rethink the entire design. Do you really need that friend declaration inside `D1`? Maybe you should somehow redesign your code to eliminate the need for that friend declaration and thus eliminate this dependency.

---

Alternatively, you can resolve it by changing `D1.h` and keeping `D2.h` unchanged. However, to follow that path you'll have to replace your "fine-grained" friend declaration

```
friend int D2::get(D1&);
```

with a more sweeping and permissive

```
friend class D2;
```

and remove the inclusion of `D2.h` from `D1.h`.

The former friend declaration requires class `D2` to be complete, which is actually what creates an "unbreakable" dependency. The latter declaration does not require `D2` to be complete.

Comment: Thanks man... The definition of 'get()' actually was the problem at first (but didn't know, then I've included .h files in both classes). Never thought of that.

Comment: Well no, actually... I could redesign the code by creating `int get_d1(){return a}` inside D1, and `int get(D1& x)` `{return x.get_d1();}` inside D2. But I thought that the first version is better?

Comment: stefaneli31: Yes, this is what I meant by "rethinking the design" and "eliminating the need for friend declaration".

Answer (score 0):

If D1's definition depends on D2 and D2's definition depends on D1, then you need to forward reference **both** classes:

```
class B;
class D1;
class D2;
```

Answer (score 0):

At the point were the code mentions `D2` there hasn't been anything to say what `D2` is (the compiler doesn't look ahead to figure it out). So you need to tell the compiler what `D2` is by adding `class D2;` before the start of the definition of `D1`.

Comment: You cannot "forward-declare" class types to use them later in friend declarations referring to their members. Class types used in such friend declarations must be *complete*. Just adding a forward-declaration `class D2;` before the definition of `class D1` will not make the friend declaration inside `D1` valid. For this reason, the only way to resolve this situation (without redesigning the class relationships) is to forward-declare `D1` before `D2`, but not the other way around.

Comment: @AndreyT - you're right. I didn't look carefully enough. The declaration in question is `D2::get(D1&)`, and the only way for the compiler to know about that member is to have seen the complete class. Note that you **don't** need the complete definition if you want to make the entire class a friend. It's sufficient to forward declare the class, or even to mention it on the fly (`friend class X`), although the latter can give you mysterious errors if you don't understand the name injection rules.